# Cache strategy in a rails application using membase, how do I make sure I don't delete everything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, memcached

I have a rails application.
I am using membase/memcache to cache DB objects and HTML partials.

I cache db objects with the create operation and of course find operations etc...
now, when I do User.find(1).
this is cached as an object in memcache.
I have a pretty good strategy with caching these along side with the HTML content.

now, when I deploy, one of the thing my Capistrano script is doing is to clear the cache (because of the html partials that change) but there's really no reason to invalidate the cache of the db objects.

How can I only delete part of my cache?
Can this be done?

my cache keys look like this
DB: user_find_by_id_10000
HTML: user_profile_home_1000

Would appreciate you help

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It might also be a good idea to user separate buckets for your DB cache and your HTML cache...then you can use the 'flush_all' command to clear out a whole bucket without affecting the other one.

Also, looking forward to Couchbase Server 2.0 which will be in a developer preview at the end of this week, you'll be able to create indexes and views to return just the data that you're looking for, you can then feed that through a little process to delete all the items that match a certain criteria.

Perry Krug
Solutions Architect, Couchbase Inc.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple to delete a cached item based on its key:

`Rails.cache.delete('user_profile_home_1000')`

In the code above I'm assuming you've set Rails' cache to use Memcached.

Comment: I have 3M keys in the cache store.
Trying to delete by keys is a bit problematic.

Comment: Oh, that's an important detail you left out of your question ;)

Comment: Sorry about that. but when said DB objects (Every User, Location, City, County, Collection... etc...) I guessed it should be clear.